# How can I easily allow users to upload multiple files?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, file-upload, upload

I'm looking for a very easy way to allow users to upload files (html) to my site. I've tried things like plupload and uploadify and they seem to difficult to implement/buggy. Are there any simple solutions out there?

Comment: i found uploadify easy to use, what's the specific issue?

Comment: I'd like to hear what your problems were as well as I've used both plu and uplodify and they seem easy and not buggy at all.

Comment: This is a little too broad for Stack Overflow, as-is. Have you tried something yet? We're here to help you when you get stuck, but in order to be on topic, this question needs to solicit a little more than a list of libraries. What specific problems did you have with what you named?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually just worked on this issue recently. Ill let you use my code i wrote. What it does is as soon as a user browses for one file, another upload box pops up and so on and so on. And then, i use phpmailer to send the files as email attachments. Look up phpmailer for more details...

The javascript to add more upload fields.. (put in HEAD)

```
<script type="text/javascript">   
function addElement()
        {
            var ni = document.getElementById('org_div1');
            var numi = document.getElementById('theValue');
            var num = (document.getElementById('theValue').value -1)+ 2;
            numi.value = num;
            var newDiv = document.createElement('div');
            var divIdName = num;  newDiv.setAttribute('id',divIdName);

            newDiv.innerHTML = '<input type="file"  class="fileupload" size="80" name="file' + (num) + '" onchange="addElement()"/> <a class="removelink" onclick=\'removeElement(' + divIdName + ')\'>Remove This File</a>';

            // add the newly created element and it's content into the DOM
            ni.appendChild(newDiv);
        }

        function removeElement(divNum)
        {
            var d = document.getElementById('org_div1');
            var olddiv = document.getElementById(divNum);

            d.removeChild(olddiv);
        }

    </script>
```

The HTML..

```
<div id="org_div1" class="file_wrapper_input">

                        <input type="hidden" value="1" id="theValue" />
<input type="file" class="fileupload" name="file1" size=
"80" onchange="addElement()" /></div>
```

The process.php page. NOTE: MUST EDIT!!! Search phpmailer and download their class.phpmailer.css class. Edit the configs in the file. Create and "uploads" directory.

```
<?php
require("css/class.phpmailer.php");





//Variables Declaration
$name = "Purchase Form";
$email_subject = "New Purchase Ticket";

$body = "geg";

foreach ($_REQUEST as $field_name => $value){
if (!empty($value)) $body .= "$field_name = $value\n\r";
}
$Email_to = "blank@blank.com"; // the one that recieves the email
$email_from = "No reply!";
//
//==== PHP Mailer With Attachment Func ====\\
//
//
//
$mail = new PHPMailer();

$mail->IsQmail();// send via SMTP MUST EDIT!!!!!
$mail->From = $email_from;
$mail->FromName = $name;
$mail->AddAddress($Email_to);
$mail->AddReplyTo($email_from);

foreach($_FILES as $key => $file){
$target_path = "uploads/";
$target_path = $target_path .basename($file['name']);

if(move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
echo "the file ".basename($file['name'])." has been uploaded";
}else {
 echo "there was an error";
}
$mail->AddAttachment($target_path);
}
$mail->Body = $body;
$mail->IsHTML(false);
$mail->Subject = $email_subject;
if(!$mail->Send())
{  echo "didnt work";
}
else {echo "Message has been sent";}


foreach($_FILES as $key => $file){
$target_path = "uploads/";
$target_path = $target_path .basename($file['name']);
unlink($target_path);}
}










?>
```

Let me know if you have any questions!!

Comment: Thanks for the help but after adding files, what is suppose to happen? I have created the uploads folder, but when I added the process.php file and the class.phpmailer.php files it still didn't work. What do I need to do to make this functional?

Comment: @Pete Well the html i gave you should go within a form tag with the action process.php ... did you do that? And in the process.php, notice is says `php require("css/class.phpmailer.php");` make sure it is the correct path!

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [jQuery Mulitple File Upload Plugin](http://www.fyneworks.com/jquery/multiple-file-upload/).  The [Uploading multiple files](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.multiple.php) page in the PHP documentation will give you an idea what the submitted result looks like and some examples for working with it.